# How to centralize imports in React components?

Tags: reactjs

After developing an application up to the delivering to mass market, I now want to improve codebase and reduce technical debts.

I realized that I have a huge amount of `import` statements at the top of my react components. In one case it's more than 50 lines.

I also realized that in almost all of my components I have some commen imports, like `React, useEffect, useState` from react library, and `TextFilter, NumericFilter, Spinner, Dialog, Show` from my internal components.

Thus even if I somehow centralize common imports, I can reduce the lines of code by at least 5% factor.

How can I reduce these lines of codes:

```
import { React, useState, useReact } from 'react';
import TextFilter from '../Components/Filters/TextFilter';
import NumericFilter from '../Components/Filters/NumericFilter';
import Dialog from '../Components/Dialog';
```

To something like this:

```
import * from 'common';
```

Also I couldn't find a good answer on the performance benchmarks related to centralizing **ALL** imports. In other words, in my application, let's say I have 180 distinct import statements, including icons.

What happens if I centralize **ALL** of them?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think that's a good thing to do as it'll stop code suggestions/syntax/docs linking from IDE. Secondly, it'll break tree shaking & cause issues. Lastly, each module in JS contains `exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname`. I think require is needed for internal code to work.
Having said that, you can create a common.js file with exports & then import from there!

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Barrelfile](https://dev.to/luispa/how-to-create-barrels-in-typescript-or-javascript-59ma).

It basically makes you create a top-level `index.ts` where you export all your components. Then you can import everything from that 1 `index.ts` file. Works for JS as well.

Another thing, I would do is use `React.useEffect` instead of destructuring `useEffect`. Reduces a lot of LOCs. But that's just my preference.

Another thing I use is relative aliases like `@/` instead of `../../`. I use it with Next.js like https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alias.
The setup depends on your build tools.
For webpack, it would look like this:
https://dev.to/georgedoescode/simplify-your-imports-with-webpack-aliases-59f

Centralizing all components might increase the danger of breaking tree shaking or adding circular dependencies. If you check your bundle size after the refactor and add some linter to check for cycles there shouldn't be a problem.